# Changing background color of a php table

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td id='col1'>" . $row['inputId'] . "</td> <td id='col2'>" . $row['inputReqDate'] . "</td> <td id='col3'>" . $row['inputOrderDate'] . "</td> <td id='col4'>" . $row['inputPriority'] . "</td><td id='col5'>" . $row['inputDescription'] . "</td>" ;
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

I need to make it so when col4 contains the text "priority" it changes the background color for the whole row. How would I go about doing this?

ps. Sorry I have not attempted any javascript, I am new to the language!

Comment: You can do something using the <col> tag, but I am not very experienced with it. Usually, I just add class to the cell and style it that way.

Comment: I was thinking adding classes to the rows or something, But i'm not sure what is possible and not possible in javascript.

Comment: everything is possible with javascript. But if you don't have to, better just use CSS.

Comment: Is this possible in pure css? 0.o

Comment: @user3625283 Actually, yes. Using the nth-child selector, you can address the n-th cell in the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just change your php to add the class to the row for you?

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr" . ($row['inputPriority'] == 'Priority' ? ' class="priority"': '') . ">";

  echo "<td id='col1'>" . $row['inputId'] . "</td> <td id='col2'>" . $row['inputReqDate'] . "</td> <td id='col3'>" . $row['inputOrderDate'] . "</td> <td id='col4'>" . $row['inputPriority'] . "</td><td id='col5'>" . $row['inputDescription'] . "</td>" ;
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Then you can just add the css for the row:

```
tr.priority {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the value, and given a match, add a css class to the row that could be styled.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  //New portion
  if($row['inputPriority'] == "priority"){
    echo "<tr class='priority'>";
  } else {
    echo "<tr>";
  }
  echo "<td id='col1'>" . $row['inputId'] . "</td> <td id='col2'>" . $row['inputReqDate'] . "</td> <td id='col3'>" . $row['inputOrderDate'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td id='col4'>" . $row['inputPriority'] . "</td><td id='col5'>" . $row['inputDescription'] . "</td>" ;
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Also, I'm guessing that you will have multiple columns labeled with id `col1`, `col2`, etc. Id's are meant to be unique on the page, you should refactor to make these attributes as classes.

For example:

```
<td class='col1'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it to the TR.

css:

```
.priority { background: red; }
```

PHP:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr  class='" . $row['inputPriority'] . "' >";
    echo "<td id='col1'>" . $row['inputId'] . "</td> <td id='col2'>" . $row['inputReqDate'] . "</td> <td id='col3'>" . $row['inputOrderDate'] . "</td> <td id='col4'>" . $row['inputPriority'] . "</td><td id='col5'>" . $row['inputDescription'] . "</td>" ;
  echo "</tr>";
}
```